# Use xkb to make shift insert parenthesis

Tags: xkb

I'm trying to imitate the setup I had on OS X (via Karabiner): Pressing the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> on its own key inserts a left <kbd>(</kbd>, but holding it down and pressing another key acts as a normal <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (and similarly with the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> & right <kbd>)</kbd>).  Is this possible with xkb?

Comment: That sounds like a cool feature. Won't be easy to do though. The first thing I thought of was [xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys). But that won't work because this doesn't allow passing on the keyevent or reacting only to keydown/keyup etc. So basically, I guess what you'd need is essentially a [keylogger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749444/listening-to-keyboard-events-without-consuming-them-in-x11-keyboard-hooking) that reacts reacts to e.g. a `keyup-LShift` event and inserts a `(` if no other key pressed.

Comment: You could use [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape), also as package in some distros, and do `xcape -e 'Shift_L=parenleft'` and `xcape -e 'Shift_R=parenright'` , but not sure it meets your needs / restrictions etc.

Comment: And that should likely be `xcape -e 'Shift_L=parenleft;Shift_R=parenright'` ...

Comment: @Sukminder xcape looks like exactly what I want, I will give that a try

Comment: @Sukminder just tried it, and it works exactly.  Want to make that comment a response & I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape).

```
xcape [-d] [-t timeout] [-e map-expression]
```

This should do the trick:

```
xcape -e 'Shift_L=parenleft;Shift_R=parenright'
```

*xcape* is included as a package for some distributions.

#### *Notes:*

It has a default delay of 500ms after which the mapped key will not be emitted. It can be set by the `-t` option.

Each *map-expression* run as a daemon and has it's own PID.